# Linux Lags On Moving/Copying Huge Files & Virtualizing

Tags: hard-disk, performance, hardware, parrotsec

I have a decent configuration, with an Intel i5 4th-Gen CPU and 12 GB of RAM,BIOS Lagecy and SATA emulation set to AHCI and the HDD is directly plugged to the Motherboard, but when I copy a big files such ISO images or do some virtualization, the cursor movements start stuttering and sometimes the OS freezes completely.

I have used Windows on the hard-drive but never gotten any of these problems .

I also ran benchmarks on the hard-drive and the health status seems good, i only get that problem on Linux; I now have Parrot Linux 4.8 (KDE version) installed, but the problem remains almost the same on different distros.

Some distros completely freeze and some try to keep up with that.  I really love Linux but this problem frustrates me specially when i multi task or use VMS (noting that my work depends on a lot of virtualization).

So, What Are The Possible Causes Of This?

Comment: its, HP don't know the exact model , the HDD is directly connected to the MB ,i don't think the problem is hardware side !

Comment: OK, what is the model part number from the serial number sticker of the HP PC?  Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: i already did answer the most of the important questions and i guess it's enough to determine the possible causes , to clarify i can't give any more information ,all i wanna know is what's might be the cause of this anything other than that i can deal with it such trouble shooting and stuff , i would be thankful if you gave me possible reasons why this might be happening so please respect my question , and thank you for your time !

Comment: Bless Your Heart. I am sure you will be able to solve it on your own.

Comment: thats funny , but i just solved it , the problem was in the sata port the HDD was plugged to it was SATA3 i plugged it back the the SATA0 tried copying some huge files n all was fine , thanks for your time even tho people will prefer some guidance and suggestions on their problem instead of total criticizing on the way that the question was put, yes i had some infos missing but you could've gave some options or things to check !

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the problem the hard drive was plugged to a Secondary SATA port (SATA3) which caused a that low performance after some research i found out how the SATA ports were labeled, and i plugged the HDD back to the a Primary SATA Port (SATA0), copied some big files for testing and it was all fine.